# Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory

Tags: crtdbg.h

I am trying to compile the cpp code in visual studio 2013.  It was working fine earlier. But now I am getting following error:

> Error 1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such
>   file or directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h  250 1   IDEditor

I checked crtdbg.h. This file exist in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include"` path.

Looks like it is not able to include above directory. 
I tried adding path in properties but still getting same problem.

```
$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include
```

Please help

Comment: For me, it is fixed by installing windows10 SDK

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue, by adding manually the missing files :
crtdbg.h then ucrt.lib.

1. crtdbg.h

   Select : VC++ Repositories => Menu General => include repositories

   Add:(Exemple for me, on x64 platform, you can search where is located this file in your machine then add the correct path)

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt
   ```
2. ucrt.lib

   Select : links editor => additional library directories

   Add:(Exemple for me, on x64 platform, you can search where is located this file
   in your machine then add the correct path)

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64
   ```
3. Clean your project then rebuild and execute the project.

You should have no errors and a compilation successfull then the console display "Hello world".

Answer (score 0):

I think that Visual Studio can't access to header file, crtdbg.h , Pease test a simple following way. Maybe it solve your problem:

1- Run as administrator Visual Studio. I emphasized run as administrator no run.

2- Open your project.

3- Add the include path in the properties.

4- Happy coding and enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

***Hello, I had a similar problem:***

When building a project (doesn't matter which one), there were a lot of errors connected with SDK files, for example, `crtdbg.h`. It happened after installing new VS Preview version, and appeared in both new and old versions (I didn't delete stable version) in any project.

*****It could be fixed** for a certain project by adding both***

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt"
```

and

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.20348.0\ucrt\x64"
```

directories to

```
Project/Properties/Linker/General/Additional_Library_Directories
```

or to

```
Project/Properties/VC++_Directories/Library_Directories
```

before other variables like this:

```
"you path to libs";$(other VS variables)$(one more variable)
```

***In the library name:***

- **10** means Windows version
- **10.0.20348.0** means SDK version
- **x64** should be the same as your project build architecture

And they **should be replaced** by your own parameters.

***But there's also a **proper solution**:***

I deleted all SDK packages from my Visual_Studio/2019/Community folder and anywhere I could find it (**but don't delete non Visual Studio SDK packages**) then installed only one SDK package instead of them all using Visual Studio Installer and its option to Modify your VS build as in the picture:
[vs_installer_menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8BB7.jpg)
And it worked fine. There also was a problem that you cannot add the common directory to your Library_Directories path, you need to choose a proper version, and the versions should be similar in all Project/Properties/Windows_SDK_version, Windows Kits Lib directory, and Windows Kits Include directory.
Otherwise it will not work. That's why it is such a headache to configure SDK properly.
*It would be probably enough to only delete them in Include and Lib folders mentioned above, try it first.*

***And the common advice I would give with SDK problems is:***

Don't install several SDK versions via Visual Studio Installer, choose only one.